# Windows Server 2016 Server Core set correct time with script

Tags: windows, docker, time

I am experimenting with windows Docker and using this repo:
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/ which contains a "Windows Server 2016 Server Core base OS image for Windows"

I need a way how to set the correct time (in my case W. Europe Standard Time) via script.

Can some please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Powershell and Set-Timezone cmdlet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-timezone

Comment: Hi Guillaume thanks for your answere. the problem is that this is not changing the time on the machine.  
`PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Date
Friday, April 21, 2017 5:24:37 PM
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-TimeZone -Name "W. Europe Standard Time"
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Date
Friday, April 21, 2017 5:25:10 PM`